# Check if a string ends with a semicolon

Tags: batch-file, cmd, compare

I am adding a file path to my PATH variable on Windows. It seems like in some cases the existing PATH ends in a semicolon and sometimes not. Therefore I have to check for this before I add my path, otherwise I might end up with a PATH string that has two semicolons. For some reason I do not understand, having ;; in your PATH creates problems. The question is now: how do I check if a string ends in a semicolon? As an example, I tried:

```
set test_1=bla;
set test_2=%test_1:~-1%
if %test_2% EQU ^; echo hello
```

But that does not work if test_2 contains a semicolon.

Comment: Try `Set "test_1=bla;"` followed by `If "%test_1:~-1%"==";" Echo hello`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you escaping the semicolon? I suggest you run the help for if  by opening cmd console and typing `if /?`

```
set "test_1=bla;"
if "%test_1:~-1%"==";" echo hello
```

We wrap the variable and the matched item in double quotes, to eliminate any possible whitespace that creeps in. So essentially you are are now matching:

```
if ";"==";"
```

which is exactly a match.

Then, as a side note. There is a chance you will be doing this in a loop. If that is the case, you need to `enabledelayedexpansion` for more on that do `setlocal /?` from cmd console.

assuming `somefilename.txt` has the following text:

```
blah;
blahblah
bla;

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%I in (somefilename.txt) do ( 
    set "test_1=%%I"
    if "!test_1:~-1!"==";" echo hello
)
```

will echo:

```
hello
hello
```

because only 2 of the items had `;` in it. but note the replacement of `%` with `!` to tell `delayedexpansion` which variables should be expanded.

Comment: Just to satisfy your curiosity, I escaped the semicolon out of desperation. I tried a few different things, and this was just one of them. I thought that maybe the semicolon was treated as a special character. But my question is answered now and all is good. Thank you very much!